# Python: Error while checking the three sides provided can able to form a triangle or not

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to find whether the given three sides can form a triangle or not, the condition to check is if the larger value(out of three) provided is less than or equal to the sum of the other two remaining value, it can form a triangle.

so i had wrote a condition like if the larger of the three value is greater than the other two remaining smaller value then it doesnt form a triangle else it forms a triangle and the code that i wrote below throws an error...

```
Def triangle_check(l1,l2,l3):
    if (l1>l2+l3) or (l2>L1+l3) or (l3>l1+l2):
        print 'No, the lengths wont form a triangle'
    elif (l1==l2+l3) or (l2==L1+l3) or (l3==l1+l2):
        print 'yes, it can form a degenerated triangle'
    else:
        print 'Yes, a triangle can be formed out of it'

length1 = raw_input('enter side 1\n')
int(length1)
length2 = raw_input('enter side 2\n')
int(length2)
length3 = raw_input('enter side 3\n')
int(length3)

triangle_check(length1,length2,length3)
```

but the worst thing is when i give different value as input, the answer am getting are not correct**strong text** i even checked the code by removing the elif condition, even then am not getting the correct answer, logically the approach is correct am sure about it, but a making some sort of mistakes while coding... can you help me ???

Comment: please correcting your code:
Def ? you mean def?
L1 or l1?
and you must re-assign lenght1 = int(length1) to get int() effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting your input in-place to an int, and then discarding it. You should change these lines to:

```
length1 = int(raw_input('enter side 1\n'))
length2 = int(raw_input('enter side 2\n'))
length3 = int(raw_input('enter side 3\n'))
```

---

There were some other syntax errors in your code. Corrected below:

```
def triangle_check(l1,l2,l3):
    if (l1>l2+l3) or (l2>l1+l3) or (l3>l1+l2):
        print 'No, the lengths wont form a triangle'
    elif (l1==l2+l3) or (l2==l1+l3) or (l3==l1+l2):
        print 'yes, it can form a degenerated triangle'
    else:
        print 'Yes, a triangle can be formed out of it'

length1 = int(raw_input('enter side 1\n'))
length2 = int(raw_input('enter side 2\n'))
length3 = int(raw_input('enter side 3\n'))

triangle_check(length1,length2,length3)
```

---

However, this way of programming is confusing, I have written a simpler algorithm for you:

```
def check_valid_triangle(sides):
    for side in sides:
        other_sides = (sum(sides)-side)
        if side > other_sides:
            return 'No'
        elif side == other_sides:
            return 'Degenerated'
    else:
        return 'Yes'

sides = []
for i in range(3):
    sides.append(int(raw_input('Enter a side:\n')))

print check_valid_triangle(sides)
```

Comment: oh you mean by default the input that am providing is int and when i type cast it, it got converted into a string ?

Comment: but even while executing the code without elif also throwing wrong answers for different value

Comment: Thanks your code is much solid than me, and it solves my case, but can you able to find what is wrong in the way i coded...

Comment: @GanapathyRamadass your syntax is wrong, see the second section of my answer where it corrects your syntax. (Def -> def, L1 -> l1, etc)